# InvalidMidiDataException: command out of range

Tags: java, javasound

I have this app from Head First Java

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMiniMusicApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();
    }
    public void play(){
        try{
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();
            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();
            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(114,1,44,100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a,1);
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            b.setMessage(128,1,44,100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b,16);
            track.add(noteOff);
            player.setSequence(seq);

            player.start();

        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("damn");
        }
    }
}
```

And this throws the following exception at runtime

```
javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException: command out of range: 0x72
    at javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.java:280)
    at MiniMiniMusicApp.play(MiniMiniMusicApp.java:15)
    at MiniMiniMusicApp.main(MiniMiniMusicApp.java:6)
```

I read some docs on setMessage and it seems the exception is thrown when you pass an invalid MidiMessage but I'm simply following the example from the book. I've read on other forums and it appears that this code works for other people.

Any idea on what is causing the issue? Can you try running this on your end and see if it works? At least that'll tell me if it's something on my environment.

Comment: seems like you are trying this code from `Head First Java book`. I also made the same typo 144 to 114 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to send a NoteOn message (`144`, not `114`). The class `ShortMessage` contains constants which prevent such mistakes. You could use it like this:

```
import static javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage.*;

a.setMessage(NOTE_ON, 1, 44, 100);
```

Such code is probably easier to read for most people than directly using the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
a.setMessage(114,1,44,100);
```

should be

```
a.setMessage(144,1,44,100);
```